# Facebook Desktop Application using restfb and netbeans

Tags: facebook, desktop-application

I am developing a desktop fb app like [yoono](http://yoono.com/).
For windows, user can open the application and update his status and read the feeds.
For this I am required to have app id.
Therefore I created a new Facebook app in link https://developers.facebook.com/apps.
But I don't understand how to integrate that Facebook app so that it works like desktop app.
I mean the code is written in my computer program not in any site etc.
Please tell me what what I do since I didn't own any website either therefore I cant provide any canvas url.

Comment: I'm not so sure what you mean by "restfb".. But if you are referring to the [old REST API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/) you should seriously consider upgrading to using the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

Comment: restfb is an api for java developers.
and it works on new Graph api.

Comment: good to know :) The name is slightly confusing :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting for desktop apps in the advanced tab. Make sure it is set to Native/Desktop.

The graph API is a web API. You send a HTML POST request to a [URL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) and receive a JSON string that you have to decode. What's a bit more complicated is authentication. Because you will need a [user access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) to query a user's friends list or personal details. Even the user's ID.

Search on the web for a Facebook API wrapper in your programming language of choice. The ones provided by facebook are obsolete (Except for the PHP one).

Comment: Thanx a lot Simon.
Let me try what u suggested me.

one more qn. Oauth support languages with web browser support like.NET, AIR.
IS java also have browser support. I think it has.